# Evaluating $I = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} u(x) dx$ through a change of variables?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, change-of-variable

I want to evaluate the following integral using change of variables but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct. It 'feels' like I should get the answer $I = 2 u(0)$.

$$
I = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} u(x) dx.
$$

Ok so here is what I'm doing. Let $\hat x = x/\varepsilon$ and $\hat u(\hat x) = u(x)$. We have $dx = \varepsilon d\hat x$ and when $x=\pm \varepsilon$ we have $\hat x = \pm 1$. So this means that

$$
\begin{align}
I & = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} u(x) dx \\
& = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \hat u(\hat x) \varepsilon d\hat x \\
& = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{-1}^{1} \hat u(\hat x) d\hat x.
\end{align}
$$
The limits no longer depends on $\varepsilon$ so we can write
\begin{align}
I & = \int_{-1}^{1} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \hat u(\hat x) d\hat x \\
& = \int_{-1}^{1} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} u(\varepsilon \hat x) d\hat x \\
& = \int_{-1}^{1}u(0) d\hat x \\
& = 2 u(0). 
\end{align}

Is this all correct and are all the steps fully rigorous?

Comment: What do you know about $u$?

Comment: The step 
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-1}^1 \hat u(\hat x)\, d \hat x = 
\int_{-1}^1 \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \hat u(\hat x)\, d \hat x
$$
needs to be justified

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged this question with distribution-theory and dirac-delta?

Comment: The question is impossible to answer unless you make some assumptions on $u$.

Comment: The desired limit is $2u(0)$ if $u$ is continuous at $0$. This follows by an immediate application of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Your steps are OK but moving the limit operator inside integral is tricky and in general requires more analysis than a typical usage of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Also any limit of the form $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}f(\epsilon)$ is independent of $\epsilon$. It is the expression $f(\epsilon) $ after the limit operator which depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Ok cool, lets assume $u$ is continuous at $0$..what do we need to justify moving the limit operator inside the integral.